# Should I use Neo4j for finding similar users or stick with something like MySQL?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, similarity, graph-databases

I'm starting a new project and although I'm used to MySQL, I'm worried about efficiency.  I'm open to other options, and graph databases sound intriguing.

I will need to find similar users based on location and rating like values.  In mysql I probably would have to join across 2 many to many relationships and order based on distance of both location and those values (euclidean distance probably).  MySQL seems slow with things like that.

I will also need to do things like find 10 nodes with text that starts with a sub string, and has the largest number of connections (which is an autocomplete I guess).

Would Neo4j or another graph database do this easily and efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Neo4J is certainly more appropriate than MySQL. I've used it myself for similarity searches and continue to do so. Check out [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html), or [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) depending on how complex your criteria are -- together with the inbuilt Lucene index, it's terrific.

Examples of what you may be trying to achieve: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/data-modeling-examples.html

Comment: I also found [this blog page](http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/webinar-follow-up-intro-to-graph.html), which list some applications that neo4j is well suited for.
Now I just have to decide on a web framework, and maybe if I should use orientdb instead of neo4j.

Comment: Great, I did the whole evaluation for a graph database- twice- once in 2010 and once late last year for two different companies. Neo4j came out the winner in both cases.

Comment: hm... I'm actually thinking OrientDB with Symfony 2.0.  OrientDB's license is a little more open, and I can't find as much about Neo4j with php.  Thanks (sorry for the tangent)

Comment: Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/P50uKuqyAak
Also: http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/11/development-setup-for-neo4j-and-php.html
You may also want to ask around on the neo4j group- folks are really helpful! http://groups.google.com/group/neo4j